remove all the character from right to left on given string
I want to remove all the character from right to left which is “8769-” from below string for example
var str = “8769-10”;
where first four characters in above str 8769 is randomly generating, and also after four characters + dash(-) will also be changing like it could be 1 to 99
I tried doing as below in js but problem is as i mentioned numbers after dash(-) could be 1 - 99
so if it is one digit number i am getting the result as expected, but if it is two digit number output is not correct,


var str = "87690-10";
newStr = str.substring(7, str.indexOf('-') + '-'.length);
console.log(newStr);



I need help to achieve the same either in php or javascript/jquery

does your prefix number before - is always fixed length or can be different?

@Alexander Nenashev, yes fixed in length, but can change randonly - rand(1111,9999)

corrected my answer

You can make use of Array.split
var str = "87690-10";
newStr = str.split('-')[1];
console.log(newStr);

This code assumes that the format of str is always the same wherein it is:
Numbers(dash)(numbers)


it's slow: https://dev.to/alexander-nenashev/avoid-intermediate-arrays-parsing-strings-to-make-you-javascript-fast-5beg

Since your prefix is fixed 4 digits + - just slice the string:


var str = "8769-10";
newStr = str.slice(5);
console.log(newStr);




Use .slice

The slice() method of Array instances returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.



var str = "87690-99";
newStr = str.slice(str.indexOf('-') + '-'.length);
console.log(newStr);




Using String#lastIndexOf instead of String#indexOf would result in better performance since it iterates from the end (if your JavaScript target supports it).
const str = '87690-10';

const dashIndex = str.lastIndexOf('-');
const newStr = str.slice(dashIndex + 1, str.length);

console.log(newStr);


nope, the result string could be 99 characters long, which is potentially bigger than looking from the beginning

@Alexander Nenashev not 99 characters, but 1 to 99 as in value

Above answer is right.But if the format of the str is fixed then you can also try this.
   var str = "8769-10";
   newStr = str.substr(5,2);
   console.log(newStr);


It's not fixed. Read the question.

@PalleDue,I know my answer is only valid id format of str is fixed.
Author mentioned

where first four characters in above str 8769 is randomly generating, and also after four characters + dash(-) will also be changing like it could be 1 to 99.
he only wants to get the last two digit.


Hi thanks,
the code should output as per digit mention in str = "8769-10" if there is 2 digit in last then only it should output 10 otherwise one didgit value, i tried you code its not working,

@dhiraj,Thanks for confirming.Try again,I have corrected the code
